# How to Send Mails with attachments from your outlook using Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, attachment

The below code works great without attachment to send 30 emails/min using outlook

the csv file i'm using having: name, email, attach
as example:

```
firstname,email@domain.com,firstfile.pdf
secondname,other@domain.com,secondfile.pdf
```

so I've set a variable for the full path of the attachments folder ( since the attachment folder is changeable

> attachments_path= "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\My\files\"

and added *message.Attachments.add (attachments_path + attach)* to the loop code

```
import csv
from time import sleep
import win32com.client as client

attachments_path= "C:\\Users\\PC\Desktop\\My\\files\\"

# create template for message body
template = "Hello {}, this is a test."


# open distribution list
with open('emails.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    distro = [row for row in reader]

# chunk distribution list into blocks of 30
chunks = [distro[x:x+30] for x in range(0, len(distro), 30)]

# create outlook instance
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

# iterate through chunks and send mail
for chunk in chunks:
    # iterate through each recipient in chunk and send mail
    for name, address, attach in chunk:
        message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        message.To = address
        message.Subject = "Subject Test"
        message.Body = template.format(name)
        message.Attachments.add (attachments_path + attach) # added for testing
        message.Send()

    # wait 60 seconds before sending next chunk
    sleep(60)
```

so when i run the code i got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\My\app.py", line 29, in <module>
    message.Attachments.add (attachments_path + attach)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 628, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

any idea how to make this code run with attachments?

Comment: How about you learn how to send email FROM python WITH python?

Comment: Thx for your reply, but i need to use outlook, to keep a record of sent mails !!

Sending emails through python With SMTP , wont keep sent messages in sent folder !

Comment: No. You need to write every email you send to the IMAP server Sent folder as well. Also possible through Python. Essentially you use SMTP to send the email then login to the IMAP server and write this same email to the Sent folder, thus creating a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure such file exists on the disk before running the code?

> message.Attachments.add (attachments_path + attach)

First of all, you need to make sure such file exists on the disk and file path contains allowed symbols in the name.

The [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method of the `Attachments` class accepts a file path string which stands for the source of the attachment. This can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

Comment: I'm sure the file exists and file names not having any symbols

Comment: What is the actual value passed to the `Add` method?

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error
the solution was only changing the file path slashes from \ to /
so instead of

```
"C:\\Users\\PC\Desktop\\My\\files\\file.pdf"
```

it should be

```
"C:/Users/PC/Desktop/My/files/file.pdf"
```